# Given two idempotents $a,b \in R$ such that $a+b$ is idempotent then $a$ and $b$ commute.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

Let $R$ be a ring with identity. An element $a \in R$ it is *idempotent* if $a^2=a$.

> Show that given two idempotents $a,b \in R$ such that $a+b$ is idempotent then $a$ and $b$ commute.

**Remark**:

I'm trying the following 
$a+b = (a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = a^2+ab+ba+b^2 = a+ab+ba+b \Rightarrow ab = - ba$. I am not able to conclude from this, I tried to $(ab)^2 = (-ba)^2$ but I can not conclude.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you get this theorem? The wording "commutes between them" is very unusual; normally you'd just say "$a$ and $b$ commute." Why were you asked/trying to show an *if and only if* statement, if at most one direction is true?

Comment: Actually it seems like the remark is a counterexample to the problem as stated. In fact, you seem very close to showing that $a + b$ is idempotent if and only if $ab = -ba$ (instead of $ab = ba$).

Comment: I do not know if that's true, but I can not find a counter-example in some noncommutative ring.

Comment: I doubt it's true.  You can probably find an example of idempotent $a, b$ where $ab \neq ba$ but $ab = -ba$ using 2 by 2 matrices.

Comment: I'm trying this ring, but all idempotent matrices whose sum is idempotent are commuting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do so using the fact that $ab = -ba$.

We have that

$ab = aabb = -abab = -baba = bbaa = ba $

I believe so is right.

Comment: Nice job. ${}{}$